# MS SQL Server: how to optimize INSERT queries

Tags: sql-server, optimization

Is there any way to optimize simple INSERT queries like the following?

```
INSERT master_table
    SELECT * FROM increment
```

The execution plan is `Table Scan` (13%) -> `Table Insert` (87%)

What can I do to make it execute faster?

Comment: Since you seem to want to select **all** columns (`SELECT *`) and **all** rows (no `WHERE` clause); there's really very little (if anything) you can do to improve this. SQL Server will need to read the **whole** source table - all rows, all columns - and that's usually a full table scan (or a clustered index scan). Not much you can do about this, really.

Answer (score 1):

You leave little choice to scan the entire table as you want all the data, however a couple of things you can do.

1. drop index, if you have any, on the `master_table`
2. use `insert into master_table with(tablock)...`

This will make the inserts into the target table as fast as possible and untilise parallel execution for reading the table to do the insert, a feature that was added in 2016.

Comment: You ignore the cost of adding the index(indexes) after the completion of the insert statement. And are you suggesting to drop the primary and all natural keys as well?

Comment: Of course there's a cost to recreate a dropped index, however in my experience the net-gain usually exceeds the cost of inserting into the table with the index present, particularly where data has to be sorted for a clustered index. As always, you have to test each to determine the best combination.